Magento 2: How to sort the attribute based on attribute label?
I have created a custom product attribute with drop-down option and added that attribute in schema.graphqls file but when checking the sorting is happening based on attribute option value not based on attribute label.
How can I sort the product attribute based on attribute label?

Do you want this on frontend side or what?

Basically I need this in graphql response as its a hybrid based project.

Have you do any code for this into graphql?

I added the attribute in the sort in graphql schema and it is working for sorting but with option value not with label.

Share the code which you try.
